# Alinear margenes

Tags: html, css, input, text

Quiero alinear la linea "Recuerda incluir un título para tu charla" con el mismo margen que los inputs y no encuentro la forma, si lo alineo con left me lo manda al margen de la pagina. Aclaro que empecé hace muy poquito y todavía uso muy pocas herramientas

```
<html>
        <body>
        <section>
            <div align="center">
                #Formulario#
            <p>Conviértete en un</p>
            <h2>ORADOR</h2>
    
            <p>Anótate como orador para dar una charla ignite. Cuéntanos de qué quieres hablar!</p>
            <form action="index2.html" method="post">
               <input class="nomb" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required> 
               <input class="apel" type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" required> 
               <input class="mail" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required> 
               <textarea class="somos" placeholder="¿Sobre qué quieres hablar?"></textarea> 
               
               <p style="font-size: 12px;">Recuerda incluir un título para tu charla</p>
              
              <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Enviar">
            </div>
               
            </form>
        </section>
        <!--fin oradores-->
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `flex` para organizar el formulario y con `text-align` definir cómo quieres que se alinee el texto, pero para eso tienes que tener en cuenta el tamaño del contenedor del texto ya que si ocupa toda la ventana entonces cuando lo alinees va a estar en el margen de la página.

```html
<html><head></head><body>
        <section>
            <div align="center">
                #Formulario#
            <p>Conviértete en un</p>
            <h2>ORADOR</h2>
    
            <p>Anótate como orador para dar una charla ignite. Cuéntanos de qué quieres hablar!</p>
            <form action="index2.html" method="post" style="display: flex;width: min-content;flex-direction: column;">
               <input class="nomb" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required=""> 
               <input class="apel" type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" required=""> 
               <input class="mail" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required=""> 
               <textarea class="somos" placeholder="¿Sobre qué quieres hablar?"></textarea> 
               
               <p style="font-size: 12px; text-align: initial;">Recuerda incluir un título para tu charla</p>
              
              <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Enviar">
            </form></div>
               
            
        </section>
        <!--fin oradores-->
    
    
    </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar width: fit-content, y el ancho del formulario se ajustara al ancho de la totalidad de los inputs, esto permitirá que el texto no se mueva totalmente a la izquierda o a la derecha de la pagina:

```
<form action="index2.html" method="post" style="width: fit-content;">
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Pude solucionarlo!